# Unexpected search results: Missing entries when paging

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, search

The following search query has a page size of 50.  On page on there are 3 entries.  On page two, there are many more, but they flicker and go away... down to 4 answers.

Any adjustment to paging options results in unexpected display of questions (too few per screen per page)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-push-notifications?page=1&sort=votes&pagesize=50

The problem is on OSX Chrome and Safari

[image]

Comment: what browser?  I don't see the same

Comment: @psubsee2003 added screenshot showing pages set to 50, and 3 questions showing plus URL bar

Comment: Probably related to me not being a 10K user?

Comment: Could be because of your ignored tags.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was that it was an ignored tag...

Comment: You can set it so that ignored tags are displayed, but slightly greyed out.