# If searching for something that's in the "ignore", prompt to remove it form ignore

Tags: feature-request, search, tag-synonyms, ignored-tags

When I first joined SO I wasn't interested in Android or iPhone development.

Now I'm starting and [realized I had unexpected search results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196112/150133) when searching for a blocked tag.

As the userbase grows and evolves in their own skill set, they may forget that something is ignored and think that Stack Overflow doesn't have the information they are looking for.

My request is if a tag, or tag synonym appears in the search results (with or without brackets), AND if the value matches an ignored tag, then a notice to the user is given... ideally to remove the ignore.

Comment: hmmm... but ignored tags are listed in the right in the home page, and this could result in a *lot* of unwanted prompts.

Comment: @AndrewBarber The ignore tags aren't aren't fully visible on the home page. They are hidden. For me, they are listed in collapsed form with an ellipsis, and it requires a second click for me to view the tags.   There will be many unwanted prompts?  I don't understand the use case.  Putting it another way; in my linked question I blocked the tags iPhone and ObjectiveC.  What should the search results look like?  Fragmented paging and weird like it is today.  Is that really the desired behavior?

Comment: I think the paging should be fixed. separate issue, imo.